# any way to sudo root but use the non-root command settings?

Tags: linux, sudo

For example, for command `sudo vim /var/log/errors.log`, I want vim to be lanuched with my own user settings instead of root settings. I know I could set up vim for root account, but it is not what I want, for it is likely to be messed up in future update. And also I don't want to change the vim behavior of other accounts.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudoedit
```

It's MUCH more secure too.
To use vim (if it's not otherwise your default editor)

```
(export VISUAL=vim; sudoedit file)
```

but even better.... set VISUAL and EDITOR in your ~/.bashrc so it is your default editor.

Answer (score 1):

I could not test, but this may work: `sudo HOME=/home/myusername vim /var/log/errors.log`

Or in a easier way: `sudo HOME=$HOME vim /var/log/errors.log`

Comment: It is nice workaround. I met errors:`Error detected while processing /home/zane/.vim/bundle/neocomplcache/plugin/neocomplcache.vim:
line   37: "sudo vim" and $HOME is not same to /root are detected.Please use sudo.vim plugin instead of sudo command or set always_set_home in sudoers`, but it seems ok.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to edit the **/etc/sudoers** file and potentially those in **/etc/sudoers.d/** and remove the **env_reset** option in the *Defaults* statements.

Mine looks like this:

```
Defaults env_reset
```

Remove, or comment out that line, and *sudo* will retain your user's environment variables, rather than dump everything and populate with a few specific values.

Of course, see the **sudoers** man page for more details, and remember to edit the sudoers file with the command **visudo** (or **sudo visudo**).  visudo checks the sudoers file for errors before it'll let you finalize the editing... if the file is bad or fails whatever checks... you can't 'sudo' anymore, thus the visudo command.

Comment: my `/etc/sudoers` and `/etc/sudoers.d/` don't have that line. I will look at the sudoers man page to see if there is anything relevent. Thanks anyway,

Comment: other options to look for are `always_set_home` and `set_home`. You may still have issues if vim is building a home path from the invoking user.